# How to pass commandline argument as part of a string parameter

Tags: c, command-line

This is part of the code I'm facing issue with :

```
void encrypt(const char *fileIn, const char *fileOut, const unsigned char *key);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
     const unsigned char key[100];
     srand(time(NULL));

     aes_init();
     encrypt(argv[1], "/home/python/encrypt/"argv[1]".encrypted", argv[3]);

     return 0;
 }
```

As you can see, in the `encrypt` function, I'm asking the user to enter the file name via command line for input. For output of the same function, I wanted the same name to be just appended by '.encrypted'. However, I get the following error whenever I try to compile the code.

```
In function ‘main’:
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘argv’
error: too few arguments to function ‘encrypt’
note: declared here
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: `"/home/python/encrypt/"argv[1]".encrypted"` this is how you manipulate it? what you want here?

Comment: The code works fine and I get the desired output(encrypted file) if I just name it as "outfile.encrypted" but I want each output file to have a different name, I.e, the original name appended by '.encrypted'. Like "trial.doc" to become "trial.doc.encrypted".

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something easy string manipulation like this

```
snprintf(key,100,"/home/python/encrypt/%s.encrypted",argv[1]);
encrypt(argv[1],key, argv[3]);
```

Comment: Note that second parameter of `snprintf` includes _null character_, so maximum possible string's length (i.e. `strlen`) is 99. Longer strings are simply cut-off.

Comment: So, I tried what you said and this is what I got -

In function ‘main' 
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘snprintf’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/usr/include/stdio.h:387:12: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘const unsigned char *’

Comment: Just remove the `const` modifer from `key`'s definition. @AnkiJu

Comment: @alk 
ok I did that. Program gets compiled! :)
but now, I'm facing something else - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: On how to debug a (small) program, you might like to read here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ @AnkiJu

Answer (score 1):

in C, string manipulation is not as smooth as in modern languages. You have to append strings by using library functions.

```
char buffer[CCHMAXPATH];
sprintf(buffer, "/home/%s.encrypted", argv[1]);
encrypt(argv[1], buffer, argv[3]);
```

Comment: This has potential UB (unless input is "trusted"), when `strlen(argv[1]) >= CCHMAXPATH - strlen("/home/python/encrypt/" ".encrypted")` (`sprintf` automatically appends _null character_).